# How to draw a polygon using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have 4 coordinates pertaining to pixel of an image. 
Say (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3) and (x4,y4).
How can I draw the polygon which passes along those 4 coordinates?

```
void cvFillPoly(CvArr* img, CvPoint** pts, int* npts, int contours, CvScalar color, int lineType=8, int shift=0)
```

Fills a polygon’s interior.

Parameters: 
img – Image

pts – Array of pointers to polygons

npts – Array of polygon vertex counters

contours – Number of contours that bind the filled region

color – Polygon color

lineType – Type of the polygon boundaries, see Line description

shift – Number of fractional bits in the vertex coordinates

This is the information. How and where can I put my coordinates.??

Can anyone explain with the code?

Comment: Eventhough this question is closed, it is still useful. I got useful knowledge by this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create an array or vector of your 4 points

```
vector<Point> points(4);
points = { (x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4) };
```

then you can use this vector as an input array.

You should use [draw approx polygon method](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=poly#approxpolydp)

```
vector<Point> approxCurve;
double epsilon = ... // choose a value.
approxPolyDP(points, approxCurve, epsilon, true);
```

Comment: Thanks. But can you be more clear.?

Comment: I'm clear with the syntax.! Was expecting an example.! And thanks btw :)